# how to use material2 input component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I see the Supported input types in the material document

- The following input types can be used with md-input-container:

  - date
  - datetime-local
  - email
  - month
  - number
  - password
  - search
  - tel
  - text
  - time
  - url
  - week

but I just see how to use mdInput or textarea, I want to know how to use other types of the input component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are standard [HTML5 `<input>` types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) on which the [`mdInput`](https://material.angular.io/components/component/input) directive can be applied. The `<input>` types that you listed would be used the same way that `type="text"` would be used.

It is up to the browser used as to how these controls are displayed and behave once rendered. For example `type="date"` will display a date picker in newer browsers.

**[MDN Form `<input>` types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) with Simple Examples**

**Date**

> **date**: HTML5 A control for entering a date (year, month, and day, with no time).

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="date"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Local Date/Time**

> **datetime-local**: HTML5 A control for entering a date and time, with no time zone.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="datetime-local"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Email**

> **email**: HTML5 A field for editing an e-mail address.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="email"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Month**

> **month**: HTML5 A control for entering a month and year, with no time zone.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="month"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Number**

> **number**: HTML5 A control for entering a number.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="number"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Password**

> **password**: A single-line text field whose value is obscured.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="password"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Search**

> **search**: HTML5 A single-line text field for entering search strings. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="search"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Telephone**

> **tel**: HTML5 A control for entering a telephone number. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value, but no other syntax is enforced. You can use attributes such as pattern and maxlength to restrict values entered in the control.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="tel"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Text**

> **text**: A single-line text field. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="text"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Time**

> **time**: HTML5 A control for entering a time value with no time zone.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="time"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**URL**

> **url**: HTML5 A field for editing a URL. The input value is validated to contain either the empty string or a valid absolute URL before submitting. You can use attributes such as pattern and maxlength to restrict values entered in the control.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="url"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

**Week**

> **week**: HTML5 A control for entering a date consisting of a week-year number and a week number with no time zone.

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput 
        type="week"
        ...>
</m-input-container>
```

Comment: i used the `type="email"` but when i input '123123123'  the valid is true, so 
 i think it does not work.  then i have this question. i try the other types,they are worked.  thank you.